# OpenCV: Floor removal from image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, robotics

I am trying to detect an object on the floor (the floor has a pattern).
The object is the cup-like thing in the middle.

I tried to use Canny and Sobel edge detection, however it detects some parts of the floor too. I also tried to HSV color filtering, however it is prone to the room's lighting. SIFT couldn't detect the object too.

How can I remove the floor from the image?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You haven't asked any question. If your question is "how do I do it?" it's too broad. [ask]

Comment: Did you try pre blurring the image before applying canny?

Comment: @Janilson yes I tried

Comment: Using a median blur with ksize = 9 before applying Canny the result looked pretty decent to me, see if it's good enough for your purposes: https://imgur.com/a/wy5Czao

Comment: @Janilson It looks great! What threshold values did you use for Canny? Thanks!

Comment: thresholds 50 and 80, apertureSize = 3 and L2 = true. Also, applying canny on the colored img seems to work better as converting to grayscale before using it makes the green and blue stripes of the box too similar to the ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use the Canny edge detector:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (5, 5), 6)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 119, 175)
    kernel = np.ones((9, 3))
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, kernel, iterations=7)
    return cv2.erode(img_dilate, kernel, iterations=7)

img = cv2.imread("lPNAJ.jpg")
contours = cv2.findContours(process(img), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]
cnt = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)[-2]
cv2.drawContours(img, [cv2.convexHull(cnt)], -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow("result", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output for the first image as input:

[image]

Output for the second image as input:

[image]

Note that the code takes the second largest contour present in the image, as the largest one belongs to the table on the right.